# How to load a docker environment through git bash?

Tags: git-bash

I'm trying to load a kedro environment with my api that we can call demo_api, it is in the downloads on my computer and when it loads it opens terminals (local hosts for me). I need to load/upload this api using git bash and VSCode, but I'm having difficulties such as: we can't find the directory and with unrecognized commands. Does anyone know a tutorial on how to do this?

Some commands I tried:

$ pwd

$ cd

$ cd demo_fastapi
bash: cd: demo_fastapi: No such file or directory

$ cd

$ pwd
/c/Users/tdomingues

$ demo_fastapi
bash: demo_fastapi: command not found

$ cd demo_fastapi
bash: cd: demo_fastapi: No such file or directory

$ cd
Display all 51 possibilities? (y or n)
Aqui fui em y e realmente está em Downloads